# Too few arguments to function, 1 passed and exactly 2 expected - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a edit function called promote(), which edits table values in the table userData.

This is the form I use

```html
<form method="post" action="{{action('PromotionsController@promote', $id )}}">
                       {{csrf_field()}}
                       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
                       <input type="text" name="rank" class="'form-control" value="{{$rankid}}" readonly />
                       <input type="text" name="id" class="'form-control" value="{{$id}}" readonly />
                       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Promote" />
                      </form>
```

The value $rankid, and $id are already placed in the form and ready to submit.
This is the controller's end.

```html
  /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function promote(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'rank' => 'required',
            'id' => 'required'
    ]);
      $promotion= userData::find($id);
      $promotion->rank = $request->get('rank');
      $promotion->id = $request->get('id');
        $promotion->save();
      return redirect()->route('home');

    }
```

I receive the error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PromotionsController::promote(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected , any alternative way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

First create a route like this

```
route::put('/promote/{id}')->name('promote.update');
```

And

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('promote.update',['id' => $id ])}}">
                   {{csrf_field()}}
                   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                   <input type="text" name="rank" class="'form-control" value="{{$rankid}}" readonly />

                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Promote" />
                  </form>
```